# How to write a Python program to determine which of these two quantities is bigger?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to determine if the factorial of n raised to the same power is larger or the factorial of (n raised to the power n).

Here's my Python code.

```
def whichIsLarger():
    def fact(n):
        assert type(n) == int
        if n == 0 or n == 1:
            return 1
        else: 
            return n * fact(n-1)
    print max( fact(n**n), fact(n)**fact(n) )
```

Will this code execute correctly (i.e. without yeilding any semantic errors)?

Is there any way of testing this code without assigning any particular value to the variable n?

I mean I would like Python to do a general (i.e. a mathematical or algebraic osrt of) comparison for me, not just the usual arithmetical one that assigning the value 8, for example, to the integer n would effect.

Is there any built-in function in Python for computing factorials?

What is the difference if we write the factorial function inside or outside of the whichIsLarger function?

Comment: What's caused my question to get downvoted, I wonder?

Comment: Did not take the time to find out how to format code in questions, did not post any attempt, did not explain where he is stuck, added statement completely irrelevant to the question, did not take the time to google basic built-in functions like `max`. Need more?

Comment: A program to determine which of 2 quantities are bigger? You mean the max() function? Or do you mean you want to know which one grows more rapidly as n tends to a certain value?

Comment: Yes, you can pass arguments to Python functions as well. It would be practically completely useless as a programming language if you had to hardcode every value.

Comment: @Juhana please have a look at my question now. I've editted it to make it more agreeable.

Comment: @timgeb can you please look at my post now? After editing, I hope to have been able to make more agreeable.

Comment: @Juhana but can I call a function in Python with an arbitrary variable as input?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why you think that you couldn't.

Comment: @MatthewLymer can you please take time having a look at my editted post? I hope it is better worded this time around.

Comment: I havent done C in a while, but I imagine that what `int n` does is actually `int n = 0` or `int n = null`. Passing that into a factorial function would cause problems I imagine

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to look at the maths for something that's gonna blow up like that. Doing it naively will mean your code will take ages to execute and you'll be repeating lots of stuff if n starts getting large. If you can get a relationship between n-1 and n you may find you can clear a lot of the work

Nonetheless, here is naive code to get you started, but you will want to try and simplify it if you can

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n *factorial(n-1)

def func1(n):
    return factorial(n)**(factorial(n))

def func2(n):
    return factorial(n**n)

for i in range(1, 5):
    val1 = func1(i)
    val2 = func2(i)
    if val1 > val2:
        print "func1 is larger: " + str(val1)
    elif val2 > val1:
        print "func2 is larger: " + str(val2)
    else:
        print "equal"
```

### **EDIT**

Recursion sucks, especially on python, go with:

```
def factorial(n):
    x = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
        x = x*i
    return x
```

Comment: First you talk about performance and then you write the factorial recursively... :)

Comment: Yeah... Python is particularly bad with recursion too isn't it?

Comment: Kinda. I'd suggest to compute all the factorials only once and store the results in a dictionary. But as a naive solution to get OP started your answer is fine.

Comment: @user3088440 thanks. But your code only compares these two quantities for n from 1 to 4. Right? What I mean to inquire about is if it is possible write code to compare these two quantities with a general n, just like we do in mathematics (although using a different approach). For example, can we write code that will tell us that 2n is always greater than n when n is any integer > 0, WITHOUT assigning n any value(s)?

Comment: I imagine that writing a general algebraic solver would be a pretty huge task. You'd probably have to do some research if you want to write it yourself. If you want it for practicality, Wolfram Alpha will solve almost anything http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import factorial

def first_equation(n):
    nf = factorial(n)
    return nf ** nf

def second_equation(n):
    return factorial(n ** n)
```

but you will very soon find that the numbers get insanely huge, you spend a long time waiting, and it really doesn't prove much because you *might* get a different result for *really* big `n`.

Instead you need to approach it symbolically. I suggest using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) - as `n -> +inf`, `n! -> (n/e)**n * (2pi * n)**0.5`

---

Another approach is to use the `sympy` symbolic math package:

```
import sympy as sp

# if you want LaTeX output, ie in iPython notebook
sp.init_printing(use_latex=True)

n = sp.symbols("n")
first_equation = sp.factorial(n) ** sp.factorial(n)
second_equation = sp.factorial(n ** n)
```

You can then use the equations directly, like

```
for n_val in range(7):
    fen = first_equation .evalf(subs={"n":n_val})
    sen = second_equation.evalf(subs={"n":n_val})
    print(n_val, fen, sen)
```

which produces

```
0 1.00000000000000 1.00000000000000
1 1.00000000000000 1.00000000000000
2 4.00000000000000 24.0000000000000
3 46656.0000000000 1.08888694504184e+28
4 1.33373577685028e+33 8.57817775342843e+506
5 3.17504237378034e+249 2.41317228491761e+9566
6 1.90281878633202e+2057 6.89642755739806e+197572
```

or symbolically, like

```
# find the limit as n -> +infinity
relation = first_equation / second_equation
limit = sp.limit(relation, n, sp.oo)
print("Limit of eq1/eq2 as n -> +inf is {}.".format(limit))
```

which produces

```
Limit of eq1/eq2 as n -> +inf is 0.
```

(that is, `(n**n)!` will become infinitely larger than `n! ** n!`.)

Comment: yes, you're right. But, can I, for example, write a Python code that will tell me that for n^2 is less than n factorial for all positive integers n > 3? Mathematically, we can show this particular fact (e.g. using induction).